# Microsoft speaker identification API: Ressource or Path can't be found

Tags: java, web-services

Hello I am trying the Microsoft speaker identification API and using the enrollment service. But I get this error in the response

> *{ "error": { "code": "NotFound", "message": "Resource or path can't be found." } }*

Here is my class code : 
package com.mscongnitive.speakeridentification;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class JavaSample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/1/enroll");
            builder.setParameter("shortAudio", "true");
            URI uri = builder.build();
            System.out.println(uri);
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b91fbd3dc22842d68e4ee1c81578d6be");
            //System.out.println(request.);


            // Request body
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\dhia1.wav");
            System.out.println(file.length());
            //StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(file.toString());
            request.setEntity( new FileEntity(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) );

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you use an IDE, have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: The request reaches the server but the server responds with a resource or path can't be found.

Comment: What will happen if you move the audio file into -let's say- "C:\\Temp" folder or into a subfolder of your server application?

Comment: I solved this problem ! it was the profileID in the url which is not recognized by the server. i wrote 0 and my profileID is 111f427c-3791-468f-b709-fc**********